# Mitigate BREACH attacks without saying goodbye to compression

Tags: apache, security

Everywhere I look for solutions to mitigate [this vulnerability](http://breachattack.com/), I find something like:

> Just disable http compression.

Well, that's a pain, because compression save a lot of bandwidth and also make your webpages load really faster. Moreover, what I read about BREACH, is that compression length can be used by an attacker to read some (potentially secret) information inside the compressed document.

Now, let's admit I do have some secret information in pages I load, that doesn't mean static resources like CSS or JS have too.

So, is it a solution to disable compression only for html pages (dynamic or not) and enable compression for non-secret resources like CSS or safe JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few potential solutions I found here

CSRF Token Defence

HTTP Chunked Encoding Mitigation

Referer Check Mitigation

https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2013/08/07/defending-against-the-breach-attack